# Alternative to using "math.round" in Google Banner ads? (Flash AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, math, random

Basically, I am trying to make a Banner ad that will go on Google's ad network. However it turns out, they don't accept ads that use math.random in the code.

So I am trying to convert my code from using math.random to call a function that simulates the same thing. I found this information on the topic, but I am stuck.

http://wondergiant.com/2013/03/random-without-math-random/

After this inserting this code and finding and replacing math.random() with getRan(20), I get no errors in my code, but the randomly generated snowflakes that I had working, no longer work. Obviously I am implementing this wrong. Can anyone tell me how I could get this to work?

Here is the original code:

```as3
function createSnow(i:int):void {
    var m:MovieClip = new snowflake();

    m.mouseEnabled = false;

    if(intro == true) {
        m.y = Math.random() * - margin *2;
        m.x = Math.random() * (sw / 2 + margin) - margin * 2;
    } else {
        m.y = Math.random() * (sh + margin*2) - margin*2;
        m.x = Math.random() * (sw + margin*2) - margin*2;
    }

    m.rotation = Math.random() * 360;
    m.depth = Math.random() * (snowZmax*2-snowZmin) + snowZmin
    m.depth = int(m.depth*100)/100
    m.scaleX = m.scaleY = Math.max(0.4, (1/(Math.max(0, m.depth))-0.5)*snowSize)
    //trace("d : "+m.depth + " = scaleX " + m.scaleX)
    if(fade == true) {
        m.alpha = 0;
    } else {
        m.alpha = newAlpha(m);
    }
    addChild(m);
    snowX(m);
    snowY(m);
}
```

If I replace all the "math.round" instances with "getRan(20)", I don't get any snowflakes, but I also do not get any errors. Any advise on how to possibly get this to work would be great!

Comment: have you tried debugging? what values are you getting as output from your `getRan()` function and how are they different from `Math.random()`

Answer (score 2):

`Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1. When you call `getRan(20)` you're asking for a number between 0 and 20. According to the [documentation](http://wondergiant.com/2013/03/random-without-math-random/), the default for the function is 1 so in your case you should be able to call it without any parameters:

```
getRan(); // Give me a random number between 0 and 1
```